# I want this script to execute fun1 and the nested fun2 functions

Tags: javascript, html

I want the script to execute the function fun1 and nested function fun2 to display the value of the variable x and the sum of x and y.

```
function  fun1 (){
    var x = 10;
    document.write(x+"<br/>");
                
    function fun2 (){
        var y = 20;
        document.write(x+y);
    }
}
        
fun1();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example you only define second function, to execute it using closures you should return it:

```
 function  fun1 (){
            var x = 10;
            document.write(x+"<br/>");

              return function fun2 (){
                    var y = 20;
                    document.write(x+y);
                }
        }
```

And then execute it by callind function 2 times, or assign to variable and the call one more time:

```
        fun1()();
        // OR
        const foo = fun1();
        foo()
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to call the function2() not to declare inside:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Closure</title>
    </head>
<body>
    <script>

        function  fun1 (){
            var x = 10;
            document.write(x+"<br/>");

               fun2(x);
        }
              function fun2 (x){
                    var y = 20;
                    document.write(x+y);
                }
        fun1();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Closures are about combining function and contexts. If `function2` is declared outside of `function1` - it doesn't have access to variable `x`